# Smart ways to extract from a ImmutableMultiDict ( Dictionary in List )

Tags: python-3.x, flask

> Python3.6.1::Anaconda 4.4.0(64bit) + Flask 0.12.2

I post my data using jQuery like this

#### Front-end

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/immutableTest',
    data: {'key': kvs },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

and `typeof kvs is an object`(array), there are many objects in it. So when `console.log(kvs)` gets

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0:{"status": "good", "color": "#414141", "describe": "The machine is running"}
  1:{"status": "error", "color": "#ff0000", "describe": "Something error with it"}
  2:{"status": "powerOff", "color": "#000000", "describe": "Closing"}
```

#### Back-end

My data looks like in back-end

```
@main.route('/immutableTest', methods=['POST'])
def immutableTest():
    for k, v in request.form.items():
    print(k, v)

key[0][status] powerOff
key[0][color] #414141
key[0][describe] The machine is running
key[1][status] error
key[1][color] #ffff00
key[1][describe] Something error with it
key[2][status] powerOff
key[2][color] #000000
key[2][describe] Closing
```

So I write my program to extract the key-value which I need. **I want to reprogram the following code.**

```
@main.route('/immutableTest', methods=['POST'])
def immutableTest():
    kvs=[]
    kv={}
    i=0
    for kk, vv in request.form.items():
        kv[kk.split('[')[2].replace(']', '')] = vv
        if i == 2:
            kvs.append(kv)
            kv={}
            i = 0
        else:
            i = i + 1
    print(kvs)
    # Script to Database to update...
    return 'Update success.'
```

This will result

```
[
  {"status": "good", "color": "#414141", "describe": "The machine is running"}, 
  {"status": "error", "color": "#ff0000", "describe": "Something error with it"}, 
  {"status": "powerOff", "color": "#000000", "describe": "Closing"}
]
```

### Is there a more manageable and standard way to get the same result?

I need the result so that I could update data in MongoDB easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to define what 'smart' means in your context. If you want more manageable and somewhat standard way to transfer structured data between a JS frontend and a Python backend, you can use JSON instead of packing your data as POST structure. For example, on the JS side:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/immutableTest',
    data: JSON.stringify(kvs),
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: 'POST'
});
```

then in your Flask app:

```
@main.route('/immutableTest', methods=['POST'])
def immutableTest():
    kvs = request.get_json()
    print(kvs)
```

And it should *automagically* transport the structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. **manageable and standard way** is what I want.